# Silex / Symfony2 Remember Me Authentication User Interface RedBean Wrapper

Tags: security, symfony, silex, remember-me, redbean

I've been trying to use RedBean ORM (http://redbeanphp.com) to implement UserInterface and UserProviderInterface of the Silex Security Provider Package.

Because of the way the RedBean ORM handles functions for its objects, I've needed to wrap the bean object in another class.

This works great for authentication, but fails tests for Remember Me functionality.

I noticed that somewhere along the chain the Security Package serializes the object.

I thought maybe this was the reason for the error, so I created properties for "id" and "password" in my wrapper class and used __sleep and __wakeup methods to ignore the bean during sleep and reload it on wakeup. Despite everything seeming to load properly during __wakeup the test for "Remember Me" functionality is still failing.

I have created a github repository of my code. If anyone has any ideas, I'd much appreciate it!

**For some reason RedBean, Silex and PHPUnit aren't allowing themselves to be included in the repository. A simple composer update should pull them down for you.** If anyone has any ideas why, I'd appreciate an answer to that as well.

**The github repository can be found at:**

https://github.com/christianmagill/silex-redbean-security

The applicable files are

**To create the test user in the database:**

/setup.php

**To run the test:**

/index.php

**My implementation of UserInterface:**

/src/App/Model/UserSecurityWrapper.php

**My implementation of UserProviderInterface:**

/src/App/Model/UserProvider.php

**My modified test:**

/src/App/Test/RememberMeRedBeanServiceProviderTest.php

**The original test:**

/vendor/silex/silex/tests/Silex/Tests/Provider/RememberMeServiceProviderTest.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with my custom UserProvider's supportsClass method. I was not taking namespacing into account. It seems like this function is not called for basic authentication, but is needed for the remember me provider.